# Escribir letra y comprobar si se encuentra en una palabra - Juego Ahorcado -

Tags: java

Estoy creando un menú en el cual preguntaré al usuario que opciones quiere escoger (esto lo he realizado con un switch dentro de un do-while) y me he atascado en la opción 2 de menú que es el juego del ahorcado, mi idea es que compruebe que la letra que he escrito está en esa palabra, en caso de que esté que la visualice y en caso de que no esté que vuelva a preguntarle al usuario que escriba otra letra de nuevo (Contabilizándole el error). ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Además de esto tengo el problema de que al haber metido todo en un do-while cuando pongo cualquier letra en el juego del ahorcado en vez de comprobármelo lo que me hace es saltarme al menú principal y no sé como solucionarlo.
PD: Me estoy enfocando en el modo fácil, cuando haga ese ya miraré como hacerlo normal y díficil

```
public class Main {
public static void main (String []args) {
    Juegos j = new Juegos ();
    j.Menu();

}
```

}

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Juegos {
private int opcion_menu = 0;
private int opcion_ahorcado;
private String n_usuario = "Desconocido";
private int num_aleatorio;
private String palabra_ahorcado;
private int n_letras_palabra_ahorcado;
private char letra;
private int max_intentos_facil = 9;
private int max_intentos_normal = 6;
private int max_intentos_dificil = 3;

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

public void Menu() {
    do {

        System.out.println("Escoge una opción :");
        System.out.println("\n [1] Introducir nombre del jugador \n [2] Jugar al ahorcado" +
                "\n [3] Jugar a Enfonsar la Flota \n [4] Vorer ultimes puntuacions \n [5] Eixir");

        try { /* Creo try catch para excepciones por si el usuario mete cualquier numero o caracter que no este en el menu */
            opcion_menu = teclado.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            opcion_menu = 1;
        }

        teclado.nextLine();
        switch (opcion_menu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Escribe tu nombre de usuario");
                n_usuario = teclado.next();
                break;

            case 2:
                ahorcado();
                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("El programa se va a finalizar, felicidades: " + n_usuario + " espero que te haya gustado el programa");
                System.out.println("Este proyecto ha sido creado por Starnix.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Introduce solo numeros entre 1 y 5");
                break;
        }
    }
    while (opcion_menu != 5);
}

public void ahorcado() {
    String palabras[] = {"criptomonedas", "apple", "microsoft", "internet", "actualizacion", "algoritmo", "antivirus", "altavoz", "arroba", "binario", "bit", "web", "comando", "contraseña", "descarga", "disco duro", "dispositivo", "documento", "ejecutar", "compilar", "depurar", "programar", "encriptar"};
    System.out.println("Escoge la dificultad deseada: \n [1] Facil \n [2] Normal \n [3] Dificil");
    opcion_ahorcado = teclado.nextInt();
    if (opcion_ahorcado == 1) {
        System.out.println("Has escogido la dificultad facil, tienes nueve intentos");
        Random r = new Random();
        num_aleatorio = r.nextInt(palabras.length);
        palabra_ahorcado = palabras[num_aleatorio];
        System.out.println(palabra_ahorcado);
        n_letras_palabra_ahorcado = palabra_ahorcado.length();
        char[] palabra_guion = new char[n_letras_palabra_ahorcado];
        for (int i = 0; i < palabra_guion.length; i++) {
            palabra_guion[i] = '_';
        }
        System.out.println(palabra_guion);

        System.out.println("Introduce una letra");
        letra = teclado.next().charAt(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < palabra_ahorcado.length(); i++) {
            if (palabra_ahorcado.charAt(i) == letra) {
                palabra_guion[i] = letra;
            }


        }

    } else if (opcion_ahorcado == 2) {
        System.out.println("Has escogido la dificultad normal, tienes seis intentos");


    } else if (opcion_ahorcado == 3) {
        System.out.println("Has escogido la dificultad dificil, tienes tres intentos");


    }
}
```

}

Comment: El problema que tienes que no has creado un bucle para seguir pidiendo letras hasta que el juego termine. Deberías tener un while... dentro del método ahorcado, ahora mismo pide una letra y se sale

Comment: no uses teclado.nextInt(); usa teclado.IntegerParseInt(nextLine); te ahorras problemas

Comment: @PabloLozano como lo hago? Creo un atributo bool llamado palabraAdivinada y pongo un while que coja al for y cuando se vuelva true que deje de recorrer el while o tú como lo harías?

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre algo así (lo he escrito sin IDE, así que quizá tenga algún fallo de compilación/ejecución):

```java
public void ahorcado() {
    
    System.out.println("Escoge la dificultad deseada: \n [1] Facil \n [2] Normal \n [3] Dificil");
    var opcionAhorcado = teclado.nextInt();
    var intentos;
    if (opcionAhorcado == 1) {
        System.out.println("Has escogido la dificultad facil, tienes nueve intentos");
        intentos = 9;
    } else {
        // otras dificultades
    }

    String palabra = obtenerPalabraAleatoria();
    System.out.println(palabra);
    char[] palabraGuion = new char[palabra.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < palabraGuion.length; i++) {
        palabraGuion[i] = '_';
    }
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(palabraGuion));

    while(intentos > 0 && faltanLetrasPorAdivinar(palabraGuion)) {
        System.out.println("Introduce una letra");
        letra = teclado.next().charAt(0);

        if (!compruebaLetra(letra, palabra, palabraGuion)) {
            intentos--;
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(palabraGuion));
    }
    if (intentos > 0) {
        //usuario ha ganado
    }
    
}

private String obtenerPalabraAleatoria() {
    String palabras[] = {"criptomonedas", "apple", "microsoft", "internet", "actualizacion", "algoritmo", "antivirus",
     "altavoz", "arroba", "binario", "bit", "web", "comando",
     "contraseña", "descarga", "disco duro", "dispositivo", "documento", "ejecutar", "compilar", "depurar", "programar", "encriptar"};
    Random r = new Random();
    numAleatorio = r.nextInt(palabras.length);
    return palabras[num_aleatorio];
}

private boolean faltanLetrasPorAdivinar(char [] guiones) {
    for (int i = 0; i < guiones.length; i++) {
        if (guiones[i] == '_') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean compruebaLetra(char letra, String palabra, char [] palabraGuion) {
    boolean coincidencia = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
        if (palabra.charAt(i) == letra) {
            palabraGuion[i] = letra;
            coincidencia = true;
        }
    }
    return coincidencia;
}
```

Se trata de que mientras queden letras por adivinar y no se hayan agotado los intentos, el usuario siga introduciendo letras. He sacado parte de la lógica a métodos privados porque el código queda más legible, es una buena práctica que te ahorra añadir comentarios (código autoexplicativo) y te da flexibilidad

Comment: Muchas gracias @Pablo y como podría hacer si en vez de adivinar letra por letra quisiese adivinar la palabra entera y en caso de que no sea esa la palabra lo que haga el programa sea descubrirme una letra de la palabra para así me sea más acertarla? Pensé en realizar un if de si la palabra escrita es la misma que la que ha seleccionado el programa del array de palabras diga enhorabuena, pero en el else no sabría como hacer para que si fallo me descubra una letra de esa palabra cada vez que falle.

Answer (score 0):

gracias a @Pablo Lozano edite el codigo. implementado en netbeans 9

```
   import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class Ahorcado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ahorcado a = new Ahorcado();
        a.ahorcado();
    }

    public void ahorcado() {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escoge la dificultad deseada: \n [1] Facil \n [2] Normal \n [3] Dificil");
        String opcionAhorcado = teclado.next();
        int intentos = 0;
        if (opcionAhorcado.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Has escogido la dificultad \n [1] Facil, tienes nueve intentos");
            intentos = 9;
        } else if (opcionAhorcado.equals("2")) {
            // otras dificultades
            System.out.println("Has escogido la dificultad\n [2] Normal, tienes seis intentos");
            intentos = 6;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Has escogido la dificultad\n [3] Dificil, tienes cuatro intentos");
            intentos = 4;
        }

        String palabra = obtenerPalabraAleatoria();
        //System.out.println(palabra);
        char[] palabraGuion = new char[palabra.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < palabraGuion.length; i++) {
            palabraGuion[i] = '_';
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(palabraGuion));

        while (intentos > 0 && faltanLetrasPorAdivinar(palabraGuion)) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una letra");
            char letra = teclado.next().charAt(0);

            if (!compruebaLetra(letra, palabra, palabraGuion)) {
                intentos--;
                System.out.println("\nCaracter incorrecto, has perdido una vida quedan: " + intentos + " intentos");
                if (intentos > 6) {
                    System.out.println(".___________    ");
                    System.out.println("|           |   ");

                } else if (intentos > 5) {
                    System.out.println(".___________    ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|          O    ");

                } else if (intentos > 4) {
                    System.out.println(".___________    ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|          O    ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|                ");
                    System.out.println("|                ");
                }else if (intentos > 3) {
                    System.out.println(".___________    ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|          O    ");
                    System.out.println("|         /|    ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");

                } 
                else if (intentos > 2) {
                    System.out.println(".___________    ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|          O    ");
                    System.out.println("|         /|\\  ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");

                } else if (intentos > 1) {
                    System.out.println(".___________    ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|          O    ");
                    System.out.println("|         /|\\  ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|           \\  ");
                }else if (intentos > 0) {
                    System.out.println(".___________     ");
                    System.out.println("|           |    ");
                    System.out.println("|           O    ");
                    System.out.println("|          /|\\  ");
                    System.out.println("|           |    ");
                    System.out.println("|          / \\  ");
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println(".___________    ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|          0    ");
                    System.out.println("|         /|\\  ");
                    System.out.println("|          |    ");
                    System.out.println("|         / \\  ");
                    System.out.println("|         ***   ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(palabraGuion));

        }
        if (intentos > 0) {
            //usuario ha ganado
            System.out.println("Has Ganado");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Game Over");
        }

    }

    private String obtenerPalabraAleatoria() {
        String palabras[] = {"criptomonedas", "apple", "microsoft", "internet",
            "actualizacion", "algoritmo", "antivirus",
            "altavoz", "arroba", "binario", "bit", "web", "comando",
            "contraseña", "descarga", "disco duro", "dispositivo", "documento",
            "ejecutar", "compilar", "depurar", "programar", "encriptar"};
        Random r = new Random();
        int numAleatorio = r.nextInt(palabras.length);
        return palabras[numAleatorio];
    }

    private boolean faltanLetrasPorAdivinar(char[] guiones) {
        for (int i = 0; i < guiones.length; i++) {
            if (guiones[i] == '_') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean compruebaLetra(char letra, String palabra, char[] palabraGuion) {
        boolean coincidencia = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
            if (palabra.charAt(i) == letra) {
                palabraGuion[i] = letra;
                coincidencia = true;
            }
        }
        return coincidencia;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pablo Lozano y starnix implementado en netbeans  9

Comment: No olvides explicar brevemente el funcionamiento de tu código, y [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.